# (jQuery) android browser input keeps always the old value while I am trying to change it

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

While i am trying to change an input value on android browsers (Firefox and Chrome)  using jquery it always keeps the old value  (old value + new value)
I've tried everything

```
$('#phone').val (newValue);
```

or

```
$('#phone').attr ('value',newValue);
```

Even by doing

```
document. getElementById ().value = newValue;
```

The result is always (old value + new value)

NB: everything is alright on desktop browsers and the value of (newVlue) is right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May the problem be the way you define `newValue`? I don't see its definition in the code you posted. Could you please edit the question showing how you define it?

Comment: it's not about newValue it's about browsers on android  (firefox and android ) because everything is doing right on desktop browsers

Comment: newValue = $('#phone').val ().slice(0,-1);